Passing an object to modal VUE
I'm having trouble with passing information to my modal.
I would like to pass a complete object to the modal.
I have a view (shortened for this purpose):
<script>
const openModal = (x, action) => {

    if (!action) {
        console.log('team: ', x)
        testObject.value = x
        action = 'new'
        modalAction.value = action

        isModalOpened.value = true;
        //partenInfo.value = teams;
        //isReceiveddata = team
        console.log('isModalOpened: ', isModalOpened.value)
</script>
<template>
<!--some more v-for stuff here...-->

<button @click="openModal(team, '')"
                                    class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Team
                                    toevoegen</button>{{ team }}</div>
                        </details>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal goes here -->
    <TeamModal :isOpen="isModalOpened" :modalAction="modalAction" :testObject="team" v-bind="team"
        @modal-close="closeModal" @submit="submitHandler" name="team-modal">
        <template #header></template>
        <template #content>
        </template>
        <template #footer="{ submit }"><button @click="submit">submit</button></template>
    </TeamModal>
</template>
<script>

the "Team toevoegen" button is firing the OpenModal function, with the team as parameter.
I've printed the value of 'team' for debugging purpose next to the button.
The output is:
{ "id": 1, "categorie": "Onder-7", "teams": [ { "id": 1, "teamnaam": "JO7-1", "categorie": 1, "extra_informatie": "bla", "laatste_update": "2024-03-30T00:00:00Z" }, { "id": 2, "teamnaam": "JO7-2", "categorie": 1, "extra_informatie": "bla", "laatste_update": "2024-03-30T00:00:00Z" } ], "teams_count": 2 }

So far so good...
But this 'object', team, I would like to have in my modal. for example with :testObject="team"
However, in the modal.vue the testObject stays empty....?
const props = defineProps({
    isOpen: Boolean,
    categorieID: String,
    modalAction: String,
    editCategorie: Object,
    testObject: Object,
    isReceiveddata: Object,
    testdata: Object,
});
</script>
<template>
Nieuw Team {{ testObject }}
</template>

this gives blank as output...
so it seems the "props" is not correctly binding to the input
What am I doing wrong?

is team in the code :testObject="team" defined somewhere as a reactive variable?  I see in your openModal function you assign testObject.value = x, so it might be your prop assignment is meant to be :testObject="testObject"

No, it's   so each "team" have their own button to add a new team, hence I need the info to put them in the correct category....

:testObject="team" this is where "testObject" should receive the teamobject information....if I'm correct

We don't really have enough code to give a concrete answer. Is TeamModal inside the v-for?  That's not clear.  If it is, and isModalOpened is true, then you'd expect multiple modals to open (one for each v-for loop).  Is that happening?  If it's not in the v-for, which would make more sense, then team is no longer in scope and you should pass :testObject="testObject" which you are already assigning the correct team value to in your openModal function (and why else would you do that?)
